# PHP: password_hash() - do I need to define the cost?

Tags: hash, php

Do I necessarily need to define the 'cost' for `password_hash()`?

Is there any default value for the cost?

I know using custom salt with `password_hash()` is not recommended.

How much time does it take to hash with `password_hash()` alone AND how much time for `password_hash()` with bcrypt?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation for `password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash), the default cost is 10. On my machine this takes about 60 ms to compute. While better than a non-adaptive hash function (think plain SHA1 or MD5), I'd prefer that be closer to 500-800ms (cost 13 on my machine). The general recommendation I make is to run some measurements on your production servers and set the cost to whatever you feel like you can reasonably handle without impacting the UX too much.

Comment: Using a random `usleep` is also a good alternative that is lighter on the CPU.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Random `usleep` won't protect data at rest in case someone gets their hands on your hashes.

Comment: In fact, `usleep` doesn't seem to protect against *anything* related to password hashing. The problem isn't a timing attack (which random sleeps don't even resolve, as they can be statistically eliminated), the problem is the cost to compute the hash.